# Rails 4.1 passing tableless calculation from create controller to new view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to wrap my head around creating a Rails 4.1 calculator that doesn't require a table.

I have a model which does the validation and holds the formulas.

```
class Formulas
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :people, :bread, :time

  validates_presence_of :people, :bread, :time

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end

  # List of formulas
  def self.calculate_sandwich_rate(people, bread, time)
    (people.to_f * bread.to_f) / time.to_f
  end
end
```

The controller looks like below.

```
class SandwichController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @formula = Formula.new
  end

  def create
    @formula = Formula.new(sandwich_params)
    if @formula.valid?
      @results = Formula.calculate_sandwich_rate(@formula.people, @formula.bread, @formula.time)
      redirect_to new_sandwich_path, notice: 'Sandwich rate is: ' + "#{@results}"
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  private
    def sandwich_params
      params.require(:formula).permit(:people, :bread, :time)
    end
end
```

View code (new.html.erb)

```
<h1> Sandwich Calculator</h1>

<%= form_for @formula do |f| %>
  <% if @formula.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@formula.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this product from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @formula.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <hr>
    Sandwich Rate: <%= @results %>
  <hr>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :people %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :people %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :bread %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :bread %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :time %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :time %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I can display the results through a flash[:notice] but I wanted it have it displayed in the view eg. `<%= @result %>` and not rely on a flash notice to display the result.

I want the `new` controller to be the default page that you fill in the field, hit submit and it will show you the results. My problem is I can't seem to add @results (from the create controller) and pass it back to the `new` view/controller.

Comment: Can you post the view code in which you are trying to do this?

Comment: Thank for replying Pavan. I have added the view code. It's a simple form_for (new.html.rb) and I'm trying to pass the @results after calculating the values from params.

Comment: Your code seems fine.What happens when you submit the form?

Comment: What happens when you change this line `@results = Formula.calculate_sandwich_rate(@formula.people, @formula.bread, @formula.time)` to `@results = Formula.calculate_sandwich_rate(params[:people], params[:bread], params[:time]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instance variables are not persisted through redirects, but you could use `session` to store the results.

```
def new
  @formula = Formula.new
  @results = session[:results]
end

def create
  @formula = Formula.new(sandwich_params)
  if @formula.valid?
    results = Formula.calculate_sandwich_rate(@formula.people, @formula.bread, @formula.time)
    session[:results] = results
    redirect_to new_sandwich_path, notice: 'Sandwich rate is: ' + "#{results}"
  else
    sesson[:results] =  nil
    render action: 'new'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you Steve for the run through. @instance variables are not persisted through redirects. I really appreciate your help.